# Expected a value of type 'double', but got one of type 'Null' The relevant error-causing widget was:

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, null

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Card(
        elevation: 6,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: groupedTransactionValues.map((data) {
              return ChartBar(
                  (data['day'] as String),
                  (data['total'] as double),
                  (totalSpending == 0.0
                      ? 0.0
                      : (data['amount'] as double) / totalSpending));
            }).toList()));
  }
}
```

he following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building chart(dirty):
Expected a value of type 'double', but got one of type 'Null'

The relevant error-causing widget was:
chart chart:file:///C:/Users/User/first_app/lib/main.dart:118:13
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

```
Why I Got This!? Please Guys Help Me :(
```

Comment: You're passing a NULL value

Comment: could you print `data` and show us it's value